# How should I set the duration of my MS program after converting from PhD?

Tags: resume, masters

I started my PhD program in CSE in Fall'16. Due to my personal and family issues, my professor agreed to convert my PhD to MS and let me graduate as early as possible in Spring, 2020. I have already finished all my course works for my MS during my PhD program. Only course that I have to take in Spring'20 is 6 hours thesis course. I converted my program from PhD to MS before Spring'20 began and will graduate in Spring'20.

Now at this stage, as I am also searching for job what should I say in my CV regarding my duration of MS completion?

Comment: Have you considered stating that you were accepted as a PhD student but had to leave with an MS for personal reasons? If you do that, there is no problem giving the actual dates.

Comment: no, I haven't considered stating about PhD. I want to only state about ms. Do I need to put my ms starting date? Is it okay if I put only expected ms graduation date?

Comment: If you do that, readers will do one of three things: Assume you took a long time for your MS, assume an employment gap, or ask for details.

Comment: If you started a degree in 2016 and you will graduate in 2020, it took you 4 years, your personal reasons are the story behind it but facts are facts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what should I say in my CV regarding my duration of MS completion?

IMHO, you should list the full time it's taken you (the 4 years, 2016-2020.)

The obvious alternatives would either be to leave a gap, or list the first few years as "Studying for PhD, not obtained" or similar. Neither of those are great alternatives, so I'd just bite the bullet, list the 4 years and go with it.

This is of course unusual, and so you should be prepared to answer a question on *why* it's taken this long - but IMHO it looks a lot less suspicious than an outright gap.